# Using boost::asio::io_service as class member field

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have class where I use boost asio library:

Header:

```
class TestIOService {

public:
    void makeConnection();
    static TestIOService getInst();

private:
    TestIOService(std::string address);
    std::string address;
    // boost::asio::io_service service;
};
```

Impl:

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/address.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include "TestIOService.h"

void TestIOService::makeConnection() {
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.2"), 1234);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    socket.close();
}

TestIOService::TestIOService(std::string address) : address(address) { }

TestIOService TestIOService::getInst() {
    return TestIOService("192.168.1.2");
}
```

And main:

```
int main(void)
{
    TestIOService service = TestIOService::getInst();
    service.makeConnection();
}
```

When I have service defined in makeConnection method with this line:

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
```

there is no problem, but when I have it as class field member(commented out in code) I get this error:

> note: ‘TestIOService::TestIOService(TestIOService&&)’ is implicitly
>   deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>        class TestIOService {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io_service` is not copyable.

You can make it shared quickly by wrapping it in `shared_ptr<io_service>`, but you should really reconsider the design first.

If your class needs to be copyable, it would logically *not* contain the `io_service` object

E.g. the following sample does create two instances of the test class not sharing a connection:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f219f1396a36cae8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TestIOService {

public:
    void makeConnection();
    static TestIOService getInst();

private:
    TestIOService(std::string address);
    std::string address;

    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> service;
};

void TestIOService::makeConnection() {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    service = boost::make_shared<io_service>();
    socket  = boost::make_shared<ip::udp::socket>(*service);
    socket->connect({ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.2"), 1234 });
    //socket->close();
}

TestIOService::TestIOService(std::string address) 
    : address(address) { }

TestIOService TestIOService::getInst() {
    return TestIOService("192.168.1.2");
}

int main() {
    auto test1 = TestIOService::getInst();
    auto test2 = TestIOService::getInst();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am not very skilled in c++ but about that design should I create new io_service for every new request?

Comment: The shared pointer would do, as long you'd call `getInst()` each time. Just copying the class won't create a new io_service though (note that _returning_ from `getInst()` tries to copy (or move) the class)

Comment: @Joe expanded with a helpful (?) example *[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f219f1396a36cae8)*

Comment: That example was really helpful, it works smoothly, about that shared_ptrs do I need to call any delete on them or are they allocated on stack?

Comment: [False dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dichotomy): They're not allocated on the stack an you don't need to call any delete on them. Also, most standard library features have documentation, as you would expect: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: I have problem using io_service.run method(example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed736ccf8c57395a ) There is operation1 and operation2 first executes ok but in second the callback is not called, I looked into wireshark and response is made. Is there error in code or something else?

Comment: Probably because `run()` exited. Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html. **Edit** Or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html

Comment: Question: is the `service = boost::make_shared<io_service>();` in `makeConnection()` really necessary? Isn't an `io_service` object already created by the default constructor?