# c++ error: use of deleted function boost::asio::io_context::io_context

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm having this error when trying to instantiate a new object of a class. The code is:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
typedef boost::asio::io_service ioservice;

class cnx
{
public:
    cnx(ioservice io);

private:
    tcp::socket *s;
};

//constructor:
cnx::cnx(ioservice io)
{
    this->s = new tcp::socket(io);
}
```

outside the cpp/h file of cnx, I try to instantiate as:

```
ioservice io;
cnx c(io);
```

or

```
cnx* c = new cnx(io);
```

and both result in this error message. What can be causing this?

Comment: `boost::asio::io_service` is not copyable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @tkausl said in the comments and also thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245244/2414842) answer, the problem was because `boost::asio::io_service` is not copyable. Changing the definition of the constructor to:

```
cnx(ioservice& io);
```

and calling it through:

```
ioservice io;
cnx c(std::ref(io));
```

solved the problem

Comment: Would you do the same for a launching a thread ?